# Laravel validation 2 different values in a single field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that would has the field that inputs 2 different values in a single field.

First field is made up with select option dropdown. Once you have selected an option from the first field, the value from the first field will print on the input field. Then in the input field you need to add or type it manually another value to make it work. So the output would look like this:

```
Selected value - Value added manually
```

So my problem is how do I validate the field if each one of them is either empty.

I have no idea what I'm doing but this is what I've tried so far but it's not working.

```
'field' => 'required|in:' . implode(",", Model::values()) . '|unique:table'
```

This should be the expected output:

- If the field value is `Selected value - Value added manually`, it is Valid.
- If the field value is `Selected value -`, it should validate to input the 2nd value.
- If the field value is `- Value added manually`, it should validate to input the 1st value.

I have searched on google but I'm not sure on what keywords should I searched on but my title sums up on what I have searched recently but I haven't found same problem as mine but if there is, please link it down thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't just use two separate fields and combine them on the server? Also, what do you mean with `it should validate to input the 2nd value.`?

Comment: @Thomas what I mean is that in a single field, there should be a 2nd value like what  I posted `Selected value - Value added manually` which is a value with a comma separated. So this sample value should be the valid output instead of just this `Selected value - `. Did you get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two separate inputs: A `select` for "selected value" and an `input` for "Value added manually". This will simplify the rules:

```
'field1' => 'required|in:' . implode(",", Model::values()),
'field2' => 'required',
```

But since you currently have a `unique` validation rule I suspect that's the reason you have it as a single field. In that case, you can create some [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

**Validate first value exists:**

```
return false !== strpos($value, '-') && strlen(trim(explode('-', $value)[0])) > 0;
```

**Validate first value is valid:**

```
return in_array($value, Model::values());
```

**Validate second value exists:**

```
return false !== strpos($value, '-') && strlen(trim(explode('-', $value)[1])) > 0;
```

You can then add those rules to the chain:

```
'field' => ['required', new FirstValueExists, new FirstValueValid, new SecondValueExists, 'unique:table'],
```

The reason I have two rules for the first value is to allow for more specific error messages ("Value 1 missing" and "Value 1 invalid"). If you don't care about that you can combine them into a single rule.

Note that I haven't actually tested this but it should work.